# Public Key Authentication using j2ssh-maverick-1.5.5.jar

Tags: authentication, key, public

Below is a code snippet for connecting to a remote server using public key authentication. I have generated public and private keys using Putty Key Gen tool and have modified the authorized_keys file in .ssh folder as required. I am able to connect to remote server using Putty and providing the prompted passphrase. I am however not able to connect via the below code. It shows me -

java.io.IOException: The PuTTY key could not be read! Invalid encryption key

Any thoughts around this ?

```
SocketTransport transport = new SocketTransport(hostname, port);
                    ssh = con.connect(transport, username);

                    FileInputStream in;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out;
                    try 
                    {
                        in = new FileInputStream("E:\\Projects\\RBL\\Finacle Interface\\Finacle\\AuthenticationKeys\\RBLTestPrivateKey.ppk");
                        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                         int read;
                         while((read = in.read()) > -1)
                           out.write(read);

                         in.close();

                         SshPrivateKeyFile pkf = SshPrivateKeyFileFactory.parse(out.toByteArray());
                         SshKeyPair pair = pkf.toKeyPair("calypso");

                         PublicKeyAuthentication pk = new PublicKeyAuthentication();
                         pk.setPrivateKey(pair.getPrivateKey());
                         pk.setPublicKey(pair.getPublicKey());

                         if(ssh.authenticate(pk)==SshAuthentication.COMPLETE)
                         {
                             Log.info(LOG_CATEGORY, "Authentication completed");
                             session = ssh.openSessionChannel();
                             return session;
                         }

                    } 
                    catch (IOException | InvalidPassphraseException | SshException e1) 
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    /*PasswordAuthentication pwd = new PasswordAuthentication();
                    pwd.setPassword(this.password); 
                    if(ssh.authenticate(pwd)==SshAuthentication.COMPLETE) 
                    {
                        session = ssh.openSessionChannel();
                        return session;
                    }*/
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    isConnected = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SshPrivateKeyFile pkf = SshPrivateKeyFileFactory.parse(new FileInputStream("E:\\Projects\\RBL\\Finacle Interface\\Finacle\\AuthenticationKeys\\TestRBL"));
                         SshKeyPair pair = pkf.toKeyPair("calypso");
```

solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you change your keypair to OpenSSH key(s), it could be work...